# Error when re-entering a Django web application

Tags: django, authentication, csrf-token

In a web application, I get a CSRF-Token error when logging back in after the user logs out. Of course, this problem only occurs when working with a smart phone.

I put the {%CSRF-TOKEN%} tag in the designed login form, but this error occurs only on smartphones and after logging out and when logging in again.

This is error:

```
ممنوع (403)
```

‏CSRF تأیید نشد. درخواست لغو شد.

Help
Reason given for failure:

```
CSRF token missing or incorrect.
```

In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when Django’s CSRF mechanism has not been used correctly. For POST forms, you need to ensure:

Your browser is accepting cookies.
The view function passes a request to the template’s render method.
In the template, there is a {% csrf_token %} template tag inside each POST form that targets an internal URL.
If you are not using CsrfViewMiddleware, then you must use csrf_protect on any views that use the csrf_token template tag, as well as those that accept the POST data.
The form has a valid CSRF token. After logging in in another browser tab or hitting the back button after a login, you may need to reload the page with the form, because the token is rotated after a login.
You’re seeing the help section of this page because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and only the initial error message will be displayed.

You can customize this page using the CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW setting.

```
<form class="login100-form validate-form" method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
                <span class="login100-form-title p-b-26">
                    ***************
                </span>
                <span class="login100-form-title p-b-48">
                    <img src="static/Images/logo.png" style="width: 
     80px; height: auto">
                </span>

                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data- 
       validate = "لطفا نام کاربری را وارد کنید">
                    {{ form.username| add_class:"input100" }}
                 {% if form.username.errors %}
                    <div class="error">
                        {% for error in form.username.errors %}
                            <span>{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}
                    <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="نام 
    کاربری"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data- 
 validate="لطفا گذرواژه را وارد کنید">
                    <span class="btn-show-pass">
                        <i class="zmdi zmdi-eye"></i>

                    </span>
                    {{ form.password| add_class:"input100" }}
                    {% if form.password.errors %}
                    <div class="error">
                        {% for error in form.password.errors %}
                            <span>{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}

                    <span class="focus-input100" data- 
placeholder="گذرواژه"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                    <div class="wrap-login100-form-btn">
                        <div class="login100-form-bgbtn"></div>
                        <button class="login100-form-btn" 
type="submit">
                            ورود
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

view.py

```
class MyLoginView(LoginView):
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('Account:tablePage')
    return super(MyLoginView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

this is error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDtGR.jpg)

Comment: Can you show the full error traceback?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.